# Access another computer's shared folder

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

Computer C is privately connected to Computer B, but Computer A & B are available in same network(can talk each other) . Now Computer C folder is mapped in Computer B (as M Drive). From computer A I am able to access Computer B (C, D drive), but I couldn't access M drive. Is there a way to access the anothers computers shared drive ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, no. You cannot enable sharing on on a network mapped drive, and network drives are not provided a $ share on connection.

This likely goes back to the older implementations of NETBIOS, which were non-routable (and computer B is acting as a router in this case). Theoretically,  WINS and NBT-over-TCP could have bridged that gap, but MS likely disabled the capability to prevent confusion up front.

Your best bet is to set Computer B up such that it can route to B from A, and then A can map their own share.

Comment: WINS is only a naming service, it does not carry any SMB traffic.

Comment: fair enough, I've change 'or' to 'and' to accommodate your concern.